# Calling an application with elevated Privileges from a normal privileged account from normal application causing issue when placed in Program Files

Tags: winforms, launch, elevated-privileges, program-files

I have a program that needs to run with normal privileges. To prevent piracy, at the launch of our application we launch a **License Manager** application that needs to run with **Elevated Privileges**. Upon enquiring with our vendors, the License Manager seems to have this elevated privileges added in its `app.manifest` file which is necessary to read some kind of **Disk ID** information, so it is mandatory (we cannot reduce its privilege requirements).

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

The application successfully launches the **License Manager** if it is placed in a normal folder. However when it is placed in Program Files folder, it seems to close at launch with no intimation.

We also checked running the application with normal credentials without adding the License Manager (it works fine).

Do we need some sort of settings to be changed either in registry or in some other windows settings to enable launching elevated privileged application from normal account. Or perhaps some code snippet needs to be added at the code launch section which can enable this scenario.

We have even tried pasting the folder created in Program Files to the Desktop (it also runs fine).

OS: Windows 7

Please let me know if any additional information is needed form my side. Any help in this direction is appreciated.

Comment: any trace of this error in event viewer?

Comment: @kennyzx, where can i find event viewer?

Comment: Google can help. Or by executing "eventvwr.exe"

Comment: @kennyzx, thanks for introducing me to the world of Event Viewer. it looks like a wonderful tool that looks really promising.

Answer (score 0):

My Humble appologies for assuming problem with **Program Files** Directory.

It turned out that the logs written by the **License Manager** were being written in the current application execution folder. The problem was caused by trying to write the log to Program Files folder when the appliction did not have the permissions to write a text file to this folder.

The logging logic was shared between the License Manager (from the program we called a function that was defined in the License Manager, which was writing logs) and the application running from the Program Files folder.

We changed the log creation folder to AppData folder. This has caused the applicaiton to launch successfully.

**Cause Conclusion:**

Writing log file in Program Files folder from an application that did not have admin privilege.

Note: I have added this post and this answer purely to help other like me, in case they dont have a solution in this type of scenario.